# POST to file on server and echo response

Tags: php, post, echo

I dont know why but i am having trouble finding out how to do this. All i want to do it post to another .php file inside the same directory and then show the contents of that page with the posted data in the browser.

I am using this but i need to access a php file that is not in the web root:

```
$post_data = http_build_query(array('stratus_code' => $this->stratus_code));
    $options = array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => $post_data));
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents('http://stratus.sylentec.com/' . $page, false, $context);
    echo $result;
```

Comment: Also, when you say "not in the web root", do you mean it is not served by the server? If your server isn't serving the PHP file, you won't be able to post to it.

Comment: Hi sorry the page is a variable containing the page that i want to post to. The php file is on my server but it is in /home/myusername and not public like /home/myusername/public_html. It is on my server tho

Answer (score 0):

$this->stratus_code is this a array? or a string?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Your not using chr(10) . chr(13) in your array pushed to stream_context_create with;

'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Hi thanks for that answer i currently have (edited code in original question)

But for some reason i cant find a way to pass post data to the .php file without it becoming and http://address. ^that doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

You cannot post anything directly to a PHP file via an http request. A PHP file is just a source file that tells the PHP interpreter, as invoked by a *web server* what to do with the incoming request.

If your PHP file is outside of your web root (in other words, your web server has no way of executing the PHP file) then you'll never be able to construct an http request that can reach your PHP file.

You either need to:

- Put your PHP file somewhere where it will be handled by your web server (e.g. in your web root)
- Use a system call to the [PHP CLI](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) to bypass the web server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, is there any way to do this with lets say a function, where i can call a function and it returns me the html?

Comment: Well, I *assumed* that you didn't just want to do an include (too obvious?), but maybe that was a false assumption. If the file exists on the same host you could just do include or require to get access to functions in the other file.